# trying to get a value from drop down of html and using that value as key to query a database and display results on same page in django

Tags: python, django, atom-editor

I have created a form drop down in  html and am trying to get the value from it then i have to query the database on that value and display the result on the same page how do I do this, please help.

Currently I am just printing the value, but am getting false in console.

```
Views.py
def AdvicePathsExperienceResourcesView(request):


    a = request.POST.get('field', False)
    print (a)
    return render(request,'FirstApp/AdvicePathsExperienceResources.html')
Template

<form method="POST">
{%csrf_token%}
  <select name="field" method="post">
    <option selected="selected" disabled>Objects on page:</option>
    <option value="Backup">Backup</option>
    <option value="Bank_Po">Bank_Po</option>
    <option value="Business">Business</option>
    <option value="CAT">CAT</option>
    <option value="IAS">IAS</option>
    <option value="GMAT">GMAT</option>
    <option value="Linux">Linux</option>
    <option value="Medical">Medical</option>
    <option value="Networking">Networking</option>
    <option value="Software Development">SoftwareDevelopmen</option>
    <option value="SSC_CGL">SSC_CGL</option>
    <option value="Storage">Storage</option>
    <option value="Wintel">Wintel</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="Select">

</select>
</form>
```

Comment: Hint: Prevent form submit event -> send selected option value to the server using ajax ->send database values as json response from the server. Try this and then post the question with error(if you encounter) and complete code.

Comment: hi thanks for reply ,i am new to all this and dont know a thing about what you said could you plaese share some blogs tutorial on things you mentioned,it would be very helpful iam trying on my end but am unable to understand things so my  solution will conatinn more non sense than solution iam willing to learn things and am excited by what you said

Comment: Then in this case it would be better if you add the model whose value you want to show and add front end cod where you want to show those values. This will help me post a complete solution.

Comment: i accepted that value from drop down into another template querired the table and displayed the result the soultion was fine